# Multiplication of three numbers in c give a wrong results?

Tags: c, multiplication

I can't belive what's happen in my program

```
double den = 180*3600*10000 ;
```

in debugging a got this value -2109934592.0000000

any help please ???

you can try this simple code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main ( int argc , char *argv )
{
double denominator =  10000*180*3600 ;

printf("%f \n", denominator ) ;
return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: That's impossible, show your entire code please.

Comment: Show the real code. Compile it with with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`)

Comment: Please check your numbers. I'm about 100% sure that these are not the correct numbers.

Comment: Should be 648000000.  I'll guess that there's a short or int overflow in there somewhere.  You didn't post the real code.

Comment: I shouldn't have answered this...I can't find the duplicated question though...

Comment: @MadScienceDreams The result won't overflow as 648,000,000 < 2,147,483,648

Comment: The provided code overflows, as the original question doesn't. FYI, 1000 < 10000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the full code in the question we can now see it's an integer overflow.

```
10000 * 180 * 3600 = 6,480,000,000.
```

This is greater than 2,147,483,648 which is the max value of a 32-bit signed int.  The results of the multiplication overflows to -2,109,934,592 and is then converted to double.

To get the right result make one of the numbers a double before you do the multiplication:

```
10000.0 * 180 * 3600
```

Comment: thanks a lot, je ne sais pas comment j ai loupé une erreur futile like that

Answer (score 1):

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:37: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
      double denominator =  10000*180*3600 ;
                                     ^
```

Is the error when I compile. Your overflowing ints and casting to a double.

```
   double denominator =  10000.0*180.0*3600.0 ;
```

Fixes the issue

Comment: how to avoid this kind of sitiuation ?

Comment: Make sure you use your suing the types you intended your original version is `double = int` which gets converted after the value has been calculated.

Comment: @user3466199 : by using a modern compiler that warns you if this happens.