# Multiplication of two variables in c++

Tags: c++, multiplication

I know it sound really stupid but I cannot understand the output of the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>  
#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>

using namespace std;


int main(){

int num_rows = 63623; // number of rows adj matrix
int num_cols = 63623; // number of columns adj matrix
int e = 334186; //number of edges

double bonferroni_lvl;
bonferroni_lvl=((num_rows*num_cols));
cout << bonferroni_lvl << endl;

}
```

If I run it on my terminal it gives:

```
-2.47081e+08
```

How is that possible? The absolute value is wrong and the sign too !

I know that I am missing something. Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: C dupe target: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428107/multiplication-of-three-numbers-in-c-give-a-wrong-results

Comment: Your `int` can't hold the value `4047886129`, so you get what's known as an overflow.

Comment: First convert your integers to `double`, then multiply them.